# In windows batch file, re-set variable inside if-else block doesn't work

Tags: windows, batch-file, variables, if-statement, set

I've got the code below, try to re-set variable "name" inside an if-else block:

```
@echo off
set name=kk
echo %name%
if "%name%"=="jj" (
echo case1
) else (
echo case2
set name=ll
echo name=%name%
)
```

Under cmd of win10, it outputs:

```
aa
kk
case2
name=kk
```

This is weird, I wish that my last echo should print:

```
name=ll
```

Seems the "set name=ll" didn't work. So would you help to explain why it didn't work as I expected, and how to fix it?

Comment: Your `set` commands are working fine, the issue you're experiencing is with your use of `%name%`. Possible duplicate of [Variables are not behaving as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected)

Comment: if you don't want to `enabledelayedexpansion` as shown by numerous duplicate questions on SO, then you can use `call echo name=%%name%%`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set name=kk
echo %name%
if "%name%"=="jj" (
  echo case1
) else (
  echo case2
  set name=ll
  echo name=!name!
)
```